# separar colunas e retirar a letra t

Tags: r, path-separator

> dados<-read.table("especies identificadas.txt",header=T,sep=",")
>   dados
>      species.......................com......sem

1              C. maculata\t               1\t3

2           C. sanguinea\t               26\t39

3             E. connexa\t               20\t14

4              H. axyridis\t               2\t7

5          H. convergens\t               12\t37

6        T. bisquinquepustulata         74\t87

7             H. festiva\t               65\t39

8           S. rubicundus\t               50\t3

9         S. demerarensis\t               10\t7

10              S. loewii\t               4\t11

11           D. agapitus  \t               2\t3

12           D. seminulus\t               15\t0
13          Sticholotidini\t               1\t0

Comment: Sugiro até mesmo diminuir a tabela de exemplo e deixar uma demonstração do que você espera obter

Answer (score 2):

Tenta modificar o separador. No seu caso, pela saída, a vírgula não é o separador das colunas.

```
dados<-read.table("especies identificadas.txt",header=T,sep="\t")
```

Comment: Já agora, `colClasses = c("character", "numeric", "numeric")` talvez seja boa ideia.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que ao colocar o "\t" como parâmetro da função o R reconhece ele como um símbolo de tabulação (o popular "Tab" do teclado) e por isso não reconhece seu separador. Entretanto, ao digitar "\\t" (para que ele reconheça o metacaractere como texto)  o `read.table` não aceita, pois o separador só pode ser um caractere. Fiz uma modificação no seu arquivo (se é possível fazer) substituir o "\t", por "|" e usei o código:

```
dados <- read.table("especies_identificadas.txt", header = F, sep = "|")
```